# UIWebView youtube video player DONE button dismisses View Controller to main app rootViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, youtube-api

**The Problem..**

My app is taking me back to my **main screen** of the app (**rootViewController**) everytime I press the **done** button after a youtube (embedded in an iframe) video gets launched from a **UIWebView** which is not what I want it to do. I just want to get back to the View Controller from where this youtube video launched and display all the content within that view.

I tried using notifications to catch the state of the **UIMoviePlayerController** to present the previous View Controller where the youtube vide launched. But, I'm also using a navigation controller, plus this View Controller depends on a previous controller selection which uses some data to display the content within the View Controller.

I REALLY NEED SOME HELP HERE, I DON'T KNOW WHAT'S THE PROBLEM..!!

**Suggestions?**
Do I need to set my own **MPMoviePlayerController**? if so, do I have to implement some delegates to be able to controller its states and what its doing?

This is how I set my UIWebView to one of the rows in my TableView

```
self.videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kElementX, kElementY, kElementWidth, 120)];
self.videoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.videoView.opaque = NO;
self.videoView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
//self.videoView.delegate = self;
[self.videoView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
self.videoView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;

[cell.contentView addSubview:self.videoView];

NSString *youtubeURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.url];

NSLog(@"youtube link -> %@", youtubeURL);

NSString *videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                       <html>\
                       <head>\
                       <style type=\"text/css\">\
                       iframe {position:absolute; top:0%%; margin-top:0px;}\
                       body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}\
                       </style>\
                       </head>\
                       <body>\
                       <div id=\"player\">\
                       <iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"100%%\" height=\"420px\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
                       </div>\
                       <script>\
                       var tag = document.createElement('script');\
                       tag.src = \"https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api\";\
                       var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];\
                       firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);\
                       var player;\
                       var myVideoId = document.getElementById('%@')\
                       function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {\
                       player = new YT.Player('player', {\
                            height: '100%%',\
                            width: '100%%',\
                            videoId: myVideoId,\
                            playerVars:{\
                                'autoplay':0,\
                                'controls':1,\
                                'enablejsapi':1,\
                                'playsinline':1,\
                                'showinfo':0\
                       events: {\
                            'onReady': onPlayerReady,\
                       }\
                       });\
                       }\
                       </script>\
                       </body>\
                       </html>", youtubeURL, self.url];

[self.videoView loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];
```

**viewDidLoad** method...

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    // Using notifications to get the state of the UIMoviePlayerController
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieIsPlaying:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieStopedPlaying:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
}

// Trying to stop the dismiss of the View Controller
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (self.videoLaunched) {
        [super viewWillDisappear:NO];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}

// apparently this function besides the notifications functions is the only one which gets call after the done button is pressed (here I tried to attempt loading back the View Controller) not much luck 
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    if(self.videoLaunched)
        [super viewWillDisappear:NO];
}


// Starts playing the video
- (void)movieIsPlaying:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.videoLaunched = YES;
}

// The video stop and exit player
- (void)movieStopedPlaying:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.videoLaunched = NO;
}
```

I really hope someone has come across with this problem and be able to share the solution with me.. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole problem was that someone the the `viewDidAppear` or actually the `NavigationViewController` was getting call and because it's set to take you back to the main or actually the `rootViewController` of the app. It's was clearing up all the previous `ViewControllers` and taking me back there.

I debugged with a break point and found the problem.. So, the solution for me was setting a variable in the `userDefaults` just before the video is about to finish with this notification `UIMoviePlayerControllerWillExitFullscreenNotification` and calling the function to set this variable, and afterwards skipping the code with an if condition in my `viewDidAppear` which all the re-settings of `ViewController` whats happening in my case..

Well, I hope it helps someone else with the same or similar problem..